# Vue has stopped showing errors in the console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm debugging a Vue/Nuxt app. For some unknown reason I'm no longer seeing errors in the console when my Javascript references a function or variable that does not exist. Instead, it just fails silently. For example,

```
methods: {
    foo() {
        doesNotExist();
    }
}
```

When I call foo() nothing happens, in both Firefox and Chrome. I used to see an error in the console.

I don't know whether this is Vue thing, a Nuxt thing, or a plain Javascript thing.

What did I do to mess things up?

Comment: set a name on each component, there will help you to debug errors

Comment: exception caught? If so, in the Firefox debugger set Breakpoints -> Pause on caught exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Try:

```
methods: {
foo: function() {
    doesNotExist();
}
```

My personal recommendation is that you use typescript for frameworks like Vue because TypeScript is a pseudo static language that compiles into javascript (dynamic) meaning that  debugging becomes infinitely easier. It’ll raise errors directly in VSCode without having to debug from devtools.

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to foo: function() did not help.

Comment: Is your Vue component registered correctly? Is it mounted? Does anything show up on the screen at all? If you post a page's source code maybe I can debug

Answer (score 1):

make sure to select Custom Levels -> Errors in your dev console:

[image: select Custom Levels -> Errors in console]

Comment: Make sure to phrase your answer in a way that doesn't make it look like you're asking a question

Comment: I think the screenshot can be helpful, thanks for adding.